# what will be the request body for create repository in azure devops?

Tags: azure

I want to create a git repository in azure devops using rest api.
POST https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/git/repositories?api-version=5.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Request body should be like this.

`{
  "name": "repo_name",
  "teamProjectReference": {
    "id": "azure_project_id"
  }
}`

Also, you can go through this link to know better https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/repositories/create?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1

Answer (score 0):

You only need to pass the repository **name** and the **project id** within the body:

```
{
  "name": "AnotherRepository",
  "project": {
    "id": "6ce954b1-ce1f-45d1-b94d-e6bf2464ba2c"
  }
}
```

See also: [Create a repository](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/repositories/create?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1#create-a-repository)